# Avoiding bandwidth cap by ISP on an Apache HTTP Web Server: encryption methods can do it?

Tags: apache, bandwidth, encryption

I got a working Apache HTTP web server on my computer so a friend (and only him, no one else) who has no computer at home could get my files directly, as from an website, from an Internet café.

I did some speed tests on my computer at home and on my computer at workplace and found out that, in both cases, I get almost full bandwidth (~7MB/s) when using protocol encryption methods in some P2P softwares (BitTorrent, eMule). This leads me to believe that this is happening because the data is hidden from their ISPs.

Well, at the same very moment, when downloading from my web server at home to my work, it goes sluggish as hell (~90KB/s)...

Is there a protocol encryption method like the one in P2P to prevent my Apache web server from being slowed down by the ISP? Or at least some alternate solution to achieve better speed in this situation? Tried HTTPS but it seemed to not work.

Answer (score 1):

Download != upload. Your upload at home will most likely be 1 Mbit (do you have an ADSL connection?), which will come down to ~ 90 KB/s.

But this doesn't belong on SO. :-)

Comment: You could test your encryption theory by creating a torrent file on your pc that shares one or a few large files, and download that from somewhere else with encrypted traffic. If it goes faster than the 90 KB/s, you could have a point and investigate further. However, HTTPS should have done the trick, though you could try using another port than the default 443.